# Modify color array java

Tags: java, arrays, colors, background-color, rgb

Attatched are 2 methods from code that prints out a gird of 25 boxes in jframe and when you click the space bar the boxes fill up one by one with random colors.  I need to modify the code so the first 13 boxes show up in shades of red and the next 12 show up only in shades of blue.  Also, I need to change the background color to a random color.  Thanks.

```
public void setColor()
{
int r = (int) (Math.random()*256);
int g = (int) (Math.random()*256);
int b = (int) (Math.random()*256);
myColors[clicked] = new Color(r,g,b);
}

public void paint(Graphics g)
{
Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

g2.setColor(Color.black);
 
counter = 0;
 
for (int x = 0; x < myFloor.length; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < myFloor[0].length; y++)
    {
        if (myColors[counter] != null)
        {
           for (int i = 0; i < counter+1; i++)
           {
              setColor();
              g2.setColor(myColors[i]);
              g2.fill(myFloor[x][y]);
           }
        }
        else
        {
           g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
           g2.draw(myFloor[x][y]);
        }
        counter++;
    }
}
}
```

I need to modify the code so the first 13 boxes show up in shades of red and the next 12 show up only in shades of blue.  Also, I need to change the background color to a random color.  Thanks.

Comment: For shades of red, hold the red value at 255.  For shades of blue, hold the blue value at 255.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc That will give you a wide gamut of colours, bounded by yellow, red, magenta and white, for what you're calling red; and bounded by cyan, blue, magenta and white for what you're calling blue.  I doubt whether that's what OP wants.

Answer (score 1):

## You could...

Use a "color blending" algorithm, which could blend a range of colors together.

The following example basically constructs a color range of dark to light red, light blue to dark blue, split over a normalised range of 0-51% and 52-100%

This has a neat side effect of filling the first 13 squares with shades of red and the last 12 with shades of blue.

[image]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private int cols = 5;
        private int rows = 5;

        private int cellSize = 50;

        private ColorGradient colorGradient;

        public TestPane() {
            colorGradient = new ColorGradient(
                    new float[]{0f, 0.51f, 0.52f, 1f},
                    new Color[]{Color.RED.darker(), Color.RED.brighter(), Color.BLUE.brighter(), Color.BLUE.darker()}
            );
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(cols * cellSize, rows * cellSize);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();

            Color borderColor = new Color(0, 0, 0, 64);

            for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
                for (int col = 0; col < cols; col++) {
                    float progress = ((row * rows) + col) / (float)(rows * cols);
                    g2d.setColor(colorGradient.colorAt(progress));
                    g2d.fillRect(col * cellSize, row * cellSize, cellSize, cellSize);
                    g2d.setColor(borderColor);
                    g2d.drawRect(col * cellSize, row * cellSize, cellSize, cellSize);
                }
            }
            g2d.dispose();
        }
    }

    public class ColorGradient {

        private float[] fractions;
        private Color[] colors;

        public ColorGradient(float[] fractions, Color[] colors) {
            this.fractions = fractions;
            this.colors = colors;
        }

        public Color colorAt(float progress) {
            Color color = null;
            if (fractions != null) {
                if (colors != null) {
                    if (fractions.length == colors.length) {
                        int[] indicies = getFractionIndicies(progress);

                        float[] range = new float[]{fractions[indicies[0]], fractions[indicies[1]]};
                        Color[] colorRange = new Color[]{colors[indicies[0]], colors[indicies[1]]};

                        float max = range[1] - range[0];
                        float value = progress - range[0];
                        float weight = value / max;

                        color = blend(colorRange[0], colorRange[1], 1f - weight);
                    } else {
                        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Fractions and colours must have equal number of elements");
                    }
                } else {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Colours can't be null");
                }
            } else {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Fractions can't be null");
            }
            return color;
        }

        protected int[] getFractionIndicies(float progress) {
            int[] range = new int[2];

            int startPoint = 0;
            while (startPoint < fractions.length && fractions[startPoint] <= progress) {
                startPoint++;
            }

            if (startPoint >= fractions.length) {
                startPoint = fractions.length - 1;
            }

            range[0] = startPoint - 1;
            range[1] = startPoint;

            return range;
        }

        protected Color blend(Color color1, Color color2, double ratio) {
            float r = (float) ratio;
            float ir = (float) 1.0 - r;

            float rgb1[] = new float[3];
            float rgb2[] = new float[3];

            color1.getColorComponents(rgb1);
            color2.getColorComponents(rgb2);

            float red = rgb1[0] * r + rgb2[0] * ir;
            float green = rgb1[1] * r + rgb2[1] * ir;
            float blue = rgb1[2] * r + rgb2[2] * ir;

            if (red < 0) {
                red = 0;
            } else if (red > 255) {
                red = 255;
            }
            if (green < 0) {
                green = 0;
            } else if (green > 255) {
                green = 255;
            }
            if (blue < 0) {
                blue = 0;
            } else if (blue > 255) {
                blue = 255;
            }

            Color color = null;
            try {
                color = new Color(red, green, blue);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException exp) {
                NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
                System.out.println(nf.format(red) + "; " + nf.format(green) + "; " + nf.format(blue));
                exp.printStackTrace();
            }
            return color;
        }
    }
}
```

Oh, and if you want to generate a random color, you could simply use something like...

```
Random rnd = new Random();
Color color = new Color(rnd.nextInt(255), rnd.nextInt(255), rnd.nextInt(255));
```

## You could...

Define the red and blue color bands separately, and then, based on the cell index, decide which band you're going to use.

This provides more "absolute" control over the decision making process.  For example, the following index allows the cells between `0-12` inclusively to draw colors from the red band and `13-24` from blue band.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class Range {

        private int lower;
        private int upper;

        public Range(int lower, int upper) {
            this.lower = lower;
            this.upper = upper;
        }

        public int getLower() {
            return lower;
        }

        public int getUpper() {
            return upper;
        }

        public boolean contains(int value) {
            return value >= getLower() && value <= getUpper();
        }

        public int getDistance() {
            return getUpper() - getLower();
        }

        public float normalised(int value) {
            return (value - getLower()) / (float)getDistance();
        }
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private int cols = 5;
        private int rows = 5;

        private int cellSize = 50;

        private ColorBand redColorBand;
        private ColorBand blueColorBand;

        private Range redRange = new Range(0, 12);
        private Range blueRange = new Range(13, 24);

        public TestPane() {
            redColorBand = new ColorBand(
                    new float[]{0f, 1f},
                    new Color[]{Color.RED.darker(), Color.RED.brighter()}
            );
            blueColorBand = new ColorBand(
                    new float[]{0f, 1f},
                    new Color[]{Color.BLUE.brighter(), Color.BLUE.darker()}
            );
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(cols * cellSize, rows * cellSize);
        }

        protected Color colorForSqaure(int index) {
            if (redRange.contains(index)) {
                return redColorBand.colorAt(redRange.normalised(index));
            } else if (blueRange.contains(index)) {
                return blueColorBand.colorAt(blueRange.normalised(index));
            }
            return Color.BLACK;
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();

            Color borderColor = new Color(0, 0, 0, 64);

            for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
                for (int col = 0; col < cols; col++) {
                    g2d.setColor(colorForSqaure(((row * rows) + col)));
                    g2d.fillRect(col * cellSize, row * cellSize, cellSize, cellSize);
                    g2d.setColor(borderColor);
                    g2d.drawRect(col * cellSize, row * cellSize, cellSize, cellSize);
                }
            }
            g2d.dispose();
        }
    }

    public class ColorBand {

        private float[] fractions;
        private Color[] colors;

        public ColorBand(float[] fractions, Color[] colors) {
            this.fractions = fractions;
            this.colors = colors;
        }

        public Color colorAt(float progress) {
            Color color = null;
            if (fractions != null) {
                if (colors != null) {
                    if (fractions.length == colors.length) {
                        int[] indicies = getFractionIndicies(progress);

                        float[] range = new float[]{fractions[indicies[0]], fractions[indicies[1]]};
                        Color[] colorRange = new Color[]{colors[indicies[0]], colors[indicies[1]]};

                        float max = range[1] - range[0];
                        float value = progress - range[0];
                        float weight = value / max;

                        color = blend(colorRange[0], colorRange[1], 1f - weight);
                    } else {
                        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Fractions and colours must have equal number of elements");
                    }
                } else {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Colours can't be null");
                }
            } else {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Fractions can't be null");
            }
            return color;
        }

        protected int[] getFractionIndicies(float progress) {
            int[] range = new int[2];

            int startPoint = 0;
            while (startPoint < fractions.length && fractions[startPoint] <= progress) {
                startPoint++;
            }

            if (startPoint >= fractions.length) {
                startPoint = fractions.length - 1;
            }

            range[0] = startPoint - 1;
            range[1] = startPoint;

            return range;
        }

        protected Color blend(Color color1, Color color2, double ratio) {
            float r = (float) ratio;
            float ir = (float) 1.0 - r;

            float rgb1[] = new float[3];
            float rgb2[] = new float[3];

            color1.getColorComponents(rgb1);
            color2.getColorComponents(rgb2);

            float red = rgb1[0] * r + rgb2[0] * ir;
            float green = rgb1[1] * r + rgb2[1] * ir;
            float blue = rgb1[2] * r + rgb2[2] * ir;

            if (red < 0) {
                red = 0;
            } else if (red > 255) {
                red = 255;
            }
            if (green < 0) {
                green = 0;
            } else if (green > 255) {
                green = 255;
            }
            if (blue < 0) {
                blue = 0;
            } else if (blue > 255) {
                blue = 255;
            }

            Color color = null;
            try {
                color = new Color(red, green, blue);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException exp) {
                NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
                System.out.println(nf.format(red) + "; " + nf.format(green) + "; " + nf.format(blue));
                exp.printStackTrace();
            }
            return color;
        }
    }
}
```

## You could...

Predefine the colors up-front

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private int cols = 5;
        private int rows = 5;

        private int cellSize = 50;

        private Color[] colors = new Color [] {
            new Color(64, 0, 0),
            new Color(79, 0, 0),
            new Color(94, 0, 0),
            new Color(109, 0, 0),
            new Color(124, 0, 0),
            new Color(139, 0, 0),
            new Color(154, 0, 0),
            new Color(169, 0, 0),
            new Color(184, 0, 0),
            new Color(199, 0, 0),
            new Color(214, 0, 0),
            new Color(229, 0, 0),
            new Color(244, 0, 0),

            new Color(0, 0, 64),
            new Color(0, 0, 80),
            new Color(0, 0, 96),
            new Color(0, 0, 112),
            new Color(0, 0, 128),
            new Color(0, 0, 144),
            new Color(0, 0, 160),
            new Color(0, 0, 176),
            new Color(0, 0, 192),
            new Color(0, 0, 208),
            new Color(0, 0, 224),
            new Color(0, 0, 240),
        };

        public TestPane() {
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(cols * cellSize, rows * cellSize);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();

            Color borderColor = new Color(0, 0, 0, 64);

            for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
                for (int col = 0; col < cols; col++) {
                    g2d.setColor(colors[((row * rows) + col)]);
                    g2d.fillRect(col * cellSize, row * cellSize, cellSize, cellSize);
                    g2d.setColor(borderColor);
                    g2d.drawRect(col * cellSize, row * cellSize, cellSize, cellSize);
                }
            }
            g2d.dispose();
        }
    }
}
```